# How to change icon on a Telerik RadToggleButton in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, telerik, togglebutton

How do I add and change icons on a Telerik RadToggleButton in a WinForms application?  I want to add something similar to the pushpins used on Telerik's documentation [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/buttons-togglebutton-overview.html).

I've tried to just change the button's Image property during my ToggleStateChanged event, but I can't see how to even reference the desired image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to figure this out, once I saw how the Designer auto-code was assigning images to these buttons.  You first have to add the images/icons to the project's Resources.resx file.

Then, the ToggleStateChanged event should look like this:

```
private void myToggleButton_ToggleStateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    RadToggleButton myButton = (RadToggleButton)sender;

    switch (args.ToggleState)
    {
        case ToggleState.On:
            myButton.Image = global::myProject.Properties.Resources.toggleOn;
            break;
        case ToggleState.Off:
            myButton.Image = global::myProject.Properties.Resources.toggleOff;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```